# Set the same height to divs in a block using Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm working on this project with Bootstrap3 and this little problem came up.
I need when the page resize que last div of this block keep the same height always.
I thought about something like setting the height to 100% but since there's divs above them with diferent height they height for 100% still different.

Maybe something using calc() but I still dont know.
Here's a picture to check whats happening:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about just define what height you want the div to be in px instead of percentage. for example :

> height = 320px

Comment: If I set a px height when I resize the page all the content will be a mess

Comment: please create jsfiddle.

Comment: which div are you setting a fixed height on?